# How to get a specific item inside the key using android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to only retrieve email addresses inside the key, not all the items. I have an items Name and Email, but I only want to retrieve EMAIL.

example:

```
Email: HOTMAIL
Email: GMAIL
```

[image: Firebase]

Comment: What is the data structure. Is it a JSON?

Answer (score 0):

first make database reference as

```
           mReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(FIREBASE_URL_USERS);
```

here FREBASE_URL_USERS is a url of users key you can get it from firebase console.
it is a combination of your unique_fiirebase_root_url / User01

then get snapshot of data as

```
        mDatabseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dataSnapshot.getValue("Email");
              // use log to check whetehr you are getting email or not 
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // log error and do something
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user emails are unique, you can [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) the users records by its email value as follows:

```
final String email = "hani.mehdi@email.com";

ValueEventListener onFindListener = new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Map<String, User> result = snapshot.getValue(Map.class);
        if (result.contains(email) {
            User user = result.get(email);
            Log.i(TAG, user.toString());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Not found: " + email);
        }
    }

};

DatabaseReference userReference = database.getReference("users")
    .orderByChild("email")
    .equalTo(email)
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(onFindListener);
```